# How to include tpl inside another tpl with parameters?

Tags: 7, theming

I have worked with `drupal 8`, i included twig template inside another twig template file like the bellow.

```
{% include module_path ~ 'templates/template.html.twig' with {
    'content': someVars,
 } 
%}
```

Now i need to do the same with Drupal 7.
Is there any way to do something similar in drupal 7 ?

Comment: Yep: [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). Scope is inherited so the `with` doesn't have an equivalent

Comment: Can you edit the question and be more specific about which template you want to include in which other and something that explains the scenario better?

Answer (score 2):

I find the best way is to use hook_theme instead of dirty requires/includes. Can make for a really nice component driven workflow.

In module or theme:

```
    /**
     * Implements hook_theme().
     */
    function mymodule_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {

      $path = drupal_get_path('theme', 'my_theme') . '/templates/components';

      return array(
        'my_template'  => array(
          'template' => 'my-template',
          'path' => $path,
          'variables' => array(
            'var1' => 'hello' 
          )
        ),
      );
    }
```

In your template

```
   print theme('my_template' array('var1' => 'yo'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is a good practice, but you can do that in your tpl:

```
<?php 
$my_content = "test";
include "archive.tpl.php";
?>
```

Then, in your archive.tpl.php you can work with $my_content

Answer (score 0):

Another option:
within the outer template call "print render(theme($variables...))".
It might also be possible call theme() in the preprocess function.